# How to add a movie in a typo3 news article

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.1.x, typo3-extensions

I'm using typo3 6.2.4 with the news extension to show some articles om my website. In one of the articles I want to add a youtube movie within a iframe. But it is not allowed to add html code. Does any one know how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about EXT:news, you can enable "Content element relations" in the extension configuration (in the Extension Manager). Then you can use every Content Element type as part of the News item, so you can add a HTML element or a Media element to display it.

By the way, if you host your video yourself, EXT:news accepts it as a media item as if it were a picture.

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I'm using. I now have changed the setting "Content element relations" but it is still the same. The youtube iframe movie is shown a normal text.